# .Find() in VBA returns empty string every time I open the Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, string, function, find

I have a `.Find()` function in VBA that I use thought macro. Happends that every time I open the Excel File and run as first the macro with the `.Find()` function gives me

> Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

But the strange thing is that, if I open my Excel File and run the other Macros first, when I run this problematic Macro it just works!

This is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub findMyCode()

    Dim valore2 As String
    Dim cell2 As Range
    Dim cellAppoggio2 As Range
    Dim cellAppoggio3 As Range
    Dim valoreFinale As String
    Dim stringaConcatena As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COMPOSIZIONE_AREE")

    Dim stringCodiceCella As String
    Dim stringDesignazioneCella As String

    valore2 = "T0" & Worksheets("CODICI").ComboBox3.Value

    Set cell2 = ws.Range("C3:EZ3").Find(valore2, Lookat:=xlPart) ' It just sets my **cell2** empty, meanwhile if I run the other Macro first, this like works!

    Set cellAppoggio2 = cell2.Offset(0, 1)

    ws.Range(cellAppoggio2.Address).EntireColumn.Insert

End sub()
```

[image: Error]

[image: Picture]

I hope I was clean as possible, if there is something missing or unclear I will update my question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207863/discussion-on-question-by-changeworld-find-in-vba-returns-empty-string-every).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I found out what was the problem, I would like to post it, so maybe would be helpful also for future users.

This was the line of code that was wrong

```
Set cell2 = ws.Range("C3:EZ3").Find(valore2, Lookat:=xlPart))
```

And this is the right one

```
Set cell2 = Worksheets("COMPOSIZIONE_AREE").Range("A3:GA3").Find(What:=Trim(valore2), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart).
```

All I did was to `Trim()` the value so I make sure that there are not spaces in the actual value and `LookIn:=xlValues` to make sure that `.Find()` is searching for values that are not formulas or other things.